# Installing Daily Build

Tags: official-repositories

Now I'm downloading 13.04 daily build ISO. I have Archlinux but I want to switch to something more stable and ubuntu is the best Linux OS imo (not just a group of packages but rly good OS). Well my question is: What version will the packages be updated to if I run system update? Will it behave as a rolling release distro or will it stop getting new, other than security updates when 13.04 final is released?

Answer (score 0):

From the version 13.04 will get all kind of updates during 9 months [as @aditya said] as it is not a LTS (long term support verion) and i will recommend you using 12.04 LTS to get 5 years of support and in 2014 14.04 LTS is comming so in 2014 you may upgrade to 14.04 LTS for further more five years. 
NON-LTS versions get full support of all kinds during there first 18 months after release.
All kind of updates ETC

Comment: Starting with 13.04, all the normal releases of Ubuntu (other than LTS releases) would be supported for 9 months instead of the usual 18 months. And Ubuntu releases do not get all the kind of updates - there are only security and bug-fix updates available. Ubuntu doesn't provide updates for newer versions of packages.

Comment: but i was commenting on the ubuntu versions not on daily releases as they are under process and only developers usually use them to report bugs

Comment: @Aditya as of 13.04 we will get in between releases updates for several packages ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind: Are you saying that from 13.04 (once it gets released) onwards Ubuntu would start providing updates for the updated version of softwares. Or are you referring to the development version of 13.04. I haven't heard anything about it - that we would be able to get new versions of softwares starting from 13.04. There are talks about providing newer version for LTS releases though.